# Longtable witdh setting ( multicolumn )

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, column-width

I am trying to make the follwing longtable shown in the picture below [image]

I have however two questions ?

1. How can I center the items of the 1st,2nd,3rd and 5th column ( Rotation, Material etc..)
2. How can I set the width of the 3 column (a lot of white space)

I would be very thankful if anybody could give me a hint here.

Here is the code I used

```
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
    
    %Tabellen
    
    \usepackage{longtable}                                      % Paket für Tabellen, die über mehrere Seiten gehen
    
    \usepackage{multicol} 
    
    \usepackage{array}  
    
    \usepackage{caption}  
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \centering
    
    
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    
    \caption[Darstellung der verschiedenen Parameter beider Versuchsgeneratoren]{Darstellung der verschiedenen Parameter beider Versuchsgeneratoren} \label{tab:Darstellung der verschiedenen Parameter beider Versuchsgeneratoren} \\
    
    \hline
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{-}} & 
    
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{-}} & 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Druckplatte}} &
    
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Pressfinger}} & 
    
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Polschuh}}\\
    
    \hline 
    
    \endfirsthead
    
    
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Fortsetzung von vorheriger Seite}} \\
    
    \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{-}} & 
    
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{-}} & 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Druckplatte}} &
    
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Pressfinger}} & 
    
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Polschuh}}\\
    
    \hline
    
    \endhead
    
    \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Fortsetzung auf der nächsten Seite}} \\ \hline
    
    \endfoot
    
    \hline 
    
    \hline
    
    \endlastfoot
    
    \textbf{Nr.} &  Luftspaltsflussdichte  &  Material & Axiale &  Rotation in ° & Radiale  & Axiale \\
      
     & & & Position & & Position & Position \\
    
      \hline
    
      & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    &  & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    & & & & & &\\
    
      \hline
    
     & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    & &  & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    & &  & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    & &  & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     & &  & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     &  & & & & &\\
    
      \hline
    
     & & & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     &  &  & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
    &  &  & & & & \\
    
      \hline
    
     &  &  & & & &  \\
    
      \hline
     
      & &  & & & & \\
     
      \hline
     &  &   & & & & \\
    
    \end{longtable}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi there! I'm not successful in tables , but I know about the fixed size of a table's columns which can be described with this code: `\begin{tabular}{|P{3cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|}
\hline
   My first column & Data & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
     \hline
     & & & & &\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}` and you can you this code inside the `\begin{table} \end{table}` environment hope this can help in any way

Comment: I think that will work as well , I haven't thought about it.  I don't use the P declaration mostly because it influences the spacing in the cell when long sentences are used inside a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With `tabularray` package is simple. All columns except firs has equal width and contents in them are centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Darstellung der verschiedenen Parameter beider Versuchsgeneratoren},
  entry = {Darstellung der verschiedenen Parameter beider Versuchsgeneratoren},
  label = {tab:Darstellung der verschiedenen Parameter beider Versuchsgeneratoren}
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                     colspec={c *{6}{X[c]}},
                     colsep=4pt,
                     row{1-2} = {font=\small\bfseries, c, b},
                     rowhead=2
                     }
--  & -- & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Druckplatte
            &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Pressfinger
                    &   &   Polschuh                    \\
Nr. &  {Luftspalt-\\ sflussdichte}  
        &  Material 
            & {Axiale\\ Position}
                & {Rotation\\ in °} 
                    & {Radiale\\ Position}  
                        & {Axiale\\ Position}   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much , this solution works.

Comment: @Zarko good and wise solution. But I didn't get how come the "Polschuh " column appears without \SetCell [] ... I just have similiar table columns and rows merging job and it isn't still done, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Programmer1988, I do not understand what is your problem.  for column header of the last column you not need `\SetCell` instruction. Fromation of the first two rows is determined by `row{1-2} = {font=\small\bfseries, c, b},` in preamble, which say: text in those rows are boldface, horizontal centered in cells and at bottom aligned. For better answer/help consider to ask a question where explain, what is your problem.